# list of lists with different lengths to data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have read many answers in SO about converting list of lists to df. But, I have noticed that they all have the length of lists (within the main big list) to be the same. I have a different case:

```
h1 <- list(USA = c(10,13,17,11), RUSSIA = NULL, BRAZIL = NULL,
  CHINA = c(11,11,10,8,12), TAIWAN = c(12,9,9,11,9,12,14), CHILE = NULL)
```

I want to convert the above list `h1` to a data.frame. My expected output should be a data.frame that has 2 columns - country_name, list. Something like this:

```
country_name, list
USA    [10, 13, 17, 11]
RUSSIA NULL
BRAZIL NULL
CHINA  [11, 11, 10, 8, 12]
TAIWAN [12, 9, 9, 11, 9, 12, 14]
CHILE  NULL
```

I did the follwing, but, did not work:

```
do.call(rbind, h1)
```

It tries to keep the column numbers same across all the rows. I do not want that. I want to see how I can use ldply to such cases. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
R> as.data.frame(as.matrix(h1))
                            V1
USA             10, 13, 17, 11
RUSSIA                    NULL
BRAZIL                    NULL
CHINA        11, 11, 10, 8, 12
TAIWAN 12, 9, 9, 11, 9, 12, 14
CHILE                     NULL

R> as.data.frame(as.matrix(h1))['TAIWAN', ]
$TAIWAN
[1] 12  9  9 11  9 12 14
```

Comment: I guess this is technically only 1 column, but you can add a "country" column with the rownames if you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a list to a matrix, where every element of the matrix will be a list.

```
d1 <- data.frame(country_name=names(h1), list=matrix(h1))
```

That said, I recommend against doing this because it does not fit the R paradigm.  Most R functions assume a matrix contains elements from one atomic type.

Comment: I agree with Joshua, typically you want to make use of the R data structure for easier/faster analysis. An alternative thing to do would be converting this data to a data frame where one column is the value and the other one is the country name (repeated as many time as the values in the list). You can achieve this using `plyr::ldply(h1, cbind)`.