# Export path sequence of all shortest path in a network

Tags: r, network-programming, igraph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have two networks in `igraph` where I'd like to extract the path sequences (not just the length) of all shortest path from the first network in the second one.
The idea behind that is:
I have stored the information of an origin-destination dataframe in `net2`. 
So I have the `start` and `end` node of trips. What I don't have is the nodes visited between `start` and `end node`. 
I assume that the agents will choose the `shortest_path` for traveling.

In `net` (first network) I have a whole network with nodes and edges attributed with travel times.
Now I would like to see how the agents in the origin-destination dataframe (`net2`) travel from the start to the end node while choosing shortest paths.

This means: I need to combine both networks. One has the information of the origin-destination relation,the other has the sequence of connecting nodes. Or in other words: Which vertices use the agents from `net2` in `net` to get to their desired node.

To get the shortest path sequence of my network `net` I used `igraph::shortest_paths`.
This gives me an `igraph.vs` object with the desired information.
Now I would like to store this information in `dataframe` but I don't know how to access it.

I tried:
`df<-unlist(shortest_paths(net,from =od$from,to=od$to)`

where od is the `origin-destination df`

Now I want to store the `multidimensional list` as a `dataframe`.

```
results <- unlist(df, recursive = F)
results <- sapply(results, as_ids)

result_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(results))
```

When I'm doing this I get the error:
`Error in UseMethod("as_ids") : 
  no applicable method for 'as_ids' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a  misspell or you are using a different version, but I can't find the `shortest_path()` function, only the one you have mentioned later: `shortest_paths()`.

If I understand clearly, you want to extract the exact shortest path sequences in a list of vertices (list of lists containing vertices), and convert it to a DF.

Here's my solution:

```
library('igraph')

set.seed(24)

g <- as.undirected(barabasi.game(20, power = 0.5, m = 4))

results <- sapply(V(g), function(x){ all_shortest_paths(g, from = x, to = V(g)[-x])$res})
results <- unlist(results, recursive = F)
results <- sapply(results, as_ids)

result_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(results))
```

I extracted the shortest paths by calling the all_short `all_shortest_paths` on each vertex, where the **from** parameter is the current vertex, and the **to** parameter is the list of the other vertices, minus the current one. Only the **res** attribute is needed from the given structure.

This gave me a multidimensional list: lists of vertex lists (every shortest path from the given vertex) for every node.

```
...
[[15]]
[[15]][[1]]
+ 3/20 vertices, from 84297ee:
[1] 15 14  1

[[15]][[2]]
+ 3/20 vertices, from 84297ee:
[1] 15  7  1

[[15]][[3]]
+ 3/20 vertices, from 84297ee:
[1] 15  5  1

[[15]][[4]]
+ 3/20 vertices, from 84297ee:
[1] 15  8  2
...
```

Once I have unlisted one layer of it, I got the inner list of vertices. This is an **igraph.vs** structure, and you have to convert it with the `sapply(,as_ids)` function as it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45082439/7530850).

After this step, you can work further with your simple list of vertex name lists, [converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875716/list-of-lists-with-different-lengths-to-data-frame-in-r) them to a data.frame

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question. I hope this points out what  I want to achieve. Also my problem changed a bit..

Comment: @copamundial Please edit your original post, with your code snippet ( your exact used graph is not needed, a random one is acceptable too, just as I showed mine ) so we can reproduce the errors. You can't simply index the shortest_paths with the vertices of another network though. I don't understand you problem either. You have a subset of the vertices of net1 in net2? Then the shortest_paths between these nodes of net2 may contain nodes of net1, that are not present in net2 though. If it's acceptable, then you can do it by: shortest_paths(net,from =V(net)[V(net2)],to=V(net)[V(net2)])

Comment: @copamundial And you can work further with these list of vertex lists as I shown you before. Just try to clarify your question a bit, and insert your code snippet please.

Comment: It's clearer now :). Just a couple of things: I don't see the accessing of the res attribute by $res if the shortest_paths structure. Secondly, does the shortest_paths give you back the proper output? I had to iterate over the __from__ attribute list, and only then it gave me the correct results. If you use my code, but change the line as results <- sapply(od[,1], function(x){ all_shortest_paths(net, from = x, to = V(net)[setdiff(od[,2],x)])$res}) and you run the rest, then it should give you the proper output

Comment: Oh I forgot about your second point. I don't know how to use ``sapply`` in the ``shortest_path`` command. I tried:

``results <- sapply(od[,1], function(x){ shortest_paths(net, from = x, to = V(net)[setdiff(od[,2],x)])$vpath})``

But get the error:
`` Error: not compatible: 
- Cols in y but not x:``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195577/discussion-between-newl-and-copamundial).

Answer (score 0):

I converted my o-d-matrix to a graph as I assume this will run faster. 
I still get the error: `Error in UseMethod("as_ids") : 
  no applicable method for 'as_ids' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"`

Might this be due to the class of my edgelist? I have vertices with IDs like: U1309? 
When I call `str(links)` it is a character. Do I need to convert the class of my edgelist? Or is there another command to turn the vertex sequence into an ordninary vector?